# How to use the filter method to remove an object from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

For example:

```
const array = [
  {
    name: JB,
    age: 28,
    dob: '12-17-1996'
  }
  {
    name: Jamey,
    age: 57
    dob: '9-13-1965'
  }
  {
    name: Jayla,
    age:30,
    dob: '11-18-1992'
  }
]
```

How would I use the filter method (and without any arrow syntax involved) to remove one of these objects from the array and iterate the updated array in Javascript?

I tried it in a for loop but it just keeps giving me undefined.

Comment: What criteria are you using for removing?

Comment: Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve].

Comment: does it throw `JB is undefined`?

Answer (score -1):

You can use `Array#filter` to obtain all elements whose name do not match the name of the object you want removed.

```js
const array=[{name:"JB",age:28,dob:"12-17-1996"},{name:"Jamey",age:57,dob:"9-13-1965"},{name:"Jayla",age:30,dob:"11-18-1992"}];
let remove = 'Jamey';
let filtered = array.filter(function(obj){
  return obj.name !== remove;
});
for (const obj of filtered) console.log(obj);
```